# Trying to find a book I read around 2008. It’s a sci-fi dystopia with a green holographic cover of a man jumping and a city behind him

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia, virtual-worlds

I read a book around 2008. It has a green holographic cover showing a guy in a city. The plot is: virtual reality has everyone addicted to the point they are obese and with bad health problems but continue to play day in and day out. Also the world is run down and I believe the protagonist is a teen or young man. Some of this information may be off I have a faint remembrance if it. Thanks to whoever is willing to help!

Comment: Was this a lenticular projection where the image shifted or changed as you looked at it from different angles? Or more of the rainbow on black background kind of "hologram"?

Comment: Question is a bit short on details but it sounds a lot like Ready Player One, except I guess it came out in 2011 and [I don't see any covers that look like what is described](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?1297291).

Answer (score 1):

Partial match might be Chris Bradford's *[Gamer](https://chrisbradford.co.uk/gamer.html)*.

[image: Front cover of Gamer]

> Scott is selected as a games tester for Virtual Kombat, the most realistic fighting video game ever invented - so real it hurts!
>
> Once a Gamer enters the fighting world, it becomes hard to distinguish between what is real and what is not.
>
> Scott must work his way up the ranks to make it out alive, but when friend and rival Kate fails to return from the Virtual Arena, Scott begins to wonder if it's more than just a game...

I don't see any mention of obesity (in fact, some of the reviews on [the Goodreads entry](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17048190-gamer) sound like most people are constantly battling for survival). As you can see above, it does have a green cover, and one of the reviews on the site mentions that it is a holographic cover. Lastly, it came out in 2012, which is a bit late for your question.